# Balancing bracket - How to determine if there's more left or right brackets

Tags: python-3.x

In addition to determining whether if an equation (str) is balanced or not, I want to be able to determine if the equation (str) has more left or right brackets, or has mismatched brackets. What changes/additions do I have to make to the following code in order to achieve what I want?

```
brackets = ["()[]{}"]
i = 0
e = 1
x = Stack()

for a in s:
    for pair in brackets:
        if a == pair[i]:
            x.push(a)
        elif a == pair[e] and not x.is_empty() and x.pop() != pair[i]:
            balanced = "Equation is not balanced"
            return balanced

if x.is_empty():
    balanced = "Equation is balanced"
    return balanced
else:
    balanced = "Equation is not balanced"
    return balanced
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the `Stack` in your code, so I use `list` instead.

```
brackets = ["()","[]","{}"]
i = 0
e = 1

x = []

def check(s):
    for a in s:
        for pair in brackets:
            if a == pair[i]:
                x.append(a)
            elif a == pair[e] and x and x.pop() != pair[i]:
                balanced = "Equation is not balanced"
                return balanced

    if not x:
        balanced = "Equation is balanced"
        return balanced
    else:
        balanced = "Equation is not balanced"
        return balanced

s = "(({[]}))[]{}"
print(check(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation does not require stack, just simple variable counter:

```
def checkForBalanced(symbolString):
    index = 0
    temp = 0
    while index < len(symbolString):
        if symbolString[index] in ['(','{','[']:
            temp++
        elif symbolString[index] in [')','}',']']:
            temp--
        else:
            pass

    return temp


def main():
    result = checkForBalanced("(2+3)-[(5-4)]")
    if result>0:
        print 'Equation has ',result,'more left brackets'
    elif result<0:
        print 'Equation has ',result,'more right brackets'
    else:
        print 'Balanced Equation'
```